# Burn bootloader into Arduino UNO from Arduino Duemilanove

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-duemilanove

I have been working with my **Arduino UNO** for 2-3 hours and after that it was not possible to load sketchs into the board since it returns a

> "avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding" error.

- The internal led "L" of the board is permanently on.

After a little research I guess that the bootloader was corrupted at some point (I still don't understand when and how).

**Q:** Apart from this board I have an **Arduino Duemilanove** board and I would like to know if it is possible to use this Duemilanove board to burn the bootloader in the broken board, is this possible? in afirmative case, how?

Since all the examples over there shows how to do it with the same board and not with a different one.

Comment: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ArduinoISP

Answer (score -1):

Yes, Nick Gammon has a page on doing that here  https://www.gammon.com.au/bootloader

Comment: Hey, a big ___ ____ to whomever downvoted this with no comment.  Nick has a great page written up, answers the question very directly, and has been in place for several years.